# Are there any security test plugins for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, plugins

Are there any tools to test the security of your rails application?

Things that can automatically test sql injection, cross-site scripting, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are any plugins out there for testing the security of your code, but here's some reading about the potential pitfalls and the fixes required for Rails apps:

1. [Quark Ruby: Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/9/20/ruby-on-rails-security-guide)
2. [Official Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Safe ERB](http://github.com/pelargir/safe_erb/tree/master) is a plugin that will raise an exception for any unescaped strings in your view templates i.e. dynamic data not escaped using the "h" method.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.ouncelabs.com/

Comment: That may be too much for what I am looking for. I was looking for something as simple (and cheap) as installing a plugin into your rails project.

Comment: They are the cheapest in the group. Otherwise you may need to outsource to others

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Rails plugin, but http://www.owasp.org/ is a good place to start.